Objectbox Version 2.3.4 no longer available on maven
In a kotlin android project I was using objectbox 2.3.4 until now.
I don't want to upgrade this version because it's enough for me, so I want to have it locally in jar or aar file instead of downloading it from maven.
I don't know how to do it, I've tried several solutions but without success, can someone tell me what to do?

Clarification: jcenter was shutdown in August 2024, you want to use Maven Central now.
ObjectBox V2.3.4 was released 2019/03/19 (!). It is highly recommended to update to the latest version. Check the ObjectBox changelogs for a list of massive improvements and fixes since then.
So, I would try to see if upgrading to 4.0.2 (latest as of 2024/09) causes any trouble. ObjectBox was rather conservative with API changes, so chances are good that you have to make no or just little changes.
If that does not work for you, you could stay with a 2.x version. 2.9.1 is available on Maven Central.

Thank you very much @MarkusJunginger for your clarification.
I know it is highly recommended to update, but we are in a very specific case with a custom android hardware / os, we cannot update gradle (6.7) and we are stuck in api 25 (
This suits us very well, so we upgraded to objectbox 3.0.1, but do you think it would be wise to integrate the objectbox library locally in the libs directory of our android project in case one day no more version of objectbox compatible with our version of gradle is available online?

jcenter announced it years ahead, so I would imagine Maven central would do something similar when it happens. It would affect millions of devs, so you would not be alone. (But ofc, to be on the safe side you could download all dependencies and backup the file yourself...)
P.S.: Please accept the answer if possible.
